# How to use Contact Point Type Consent in SFMC Journeys with Salesforce Data as Entry Source

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, cloud, consent-management

How are we supposed to check for Person Account/ Lead email opt-in status stored in Contact Point Type Consent when triggering Journeys in SFMC Salesforce Data Entry Event?

I know it is possible to do a decision split and lookup the Synchronised DE but how about Journeys that would be triggered to new Contacts & Leads that haven't even been synchronised into SFMC?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify the problem please - do you mean that you are sending contacts to a journey right after they’ve been created, before the 15 min refresh of the synched data happens? In that case, why not add a wait activity at the beginning of the journey?

Comment: Hi Zuzanna, thanks for getting back to me. Yes - that's the problem. The whole point of using Salesforce Data Entry Events is to start communicating with the subscriber as soon as certain action happens (near real time). With Salesforce wanting everyone to start using that Preferences Contact Model I think there should be a way of checking subscriber's status directly in CRM and not in Synchronised DEs.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose to include related data when you define your trigger in SFMC, this way you have the data instantly available as Journey Data instead of waiting for the sync DEs. E.g. for Contacts you can include all sorts of Account attributes to be included. The trick is to ensure the data is processed and modelled in CRM properly so that you can rely on it. This of course depends completely on your business so it's hard to say anything general about it.